# git push error -> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/master (ref exists)

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to do a git push as shown below

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/master
```

It is giving the below logs

```
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 454 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1)
To ssh://deepu.t@...
```

I am getting below error after that

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/master (ref exists)
```

I have searched and couldn't find anything related to this error.

> (ref exits)

Please help!!

Comment: What a strange way to push.  Are you just trying to push work to master?

Comment: I was missing "for"!!

Comment: @Makoto this is because of Deepu is using Gerrit

Comment: @StephenKing:  Alright, fair enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) for the `master` branch is either `master` or `refs/heads/master`.  So either one of the following should work:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

As you appear to be using Gerrit (I'm assuming because you've used the [gerrit](/questions/tagged/gerrit) tag in your question), you might not be authorized to push directly into the master branch, depending on how your Gerrit is configured. If you intend to push your changes into code-review instead of directly into the `master` branch, use the `refs/for/master` refspec:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I am using gerrit and git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master worked.